# Finding Source MAC Address of A Packet

Tags: routing, layer2

Let's say a packet originates from an internal network (with a private IP). Even after this packet leaves the gateway router, the MAC address of the originating host is still somewhere in this packet (right?). Where in this packet might I look to find this originating host MAC?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can't find the source mac adress once it leaves the respectiv L2 segment , the last device that is capable of seeing the L2 adress is the gateway .
In some networks you can see the mac adress as a payload sent to another device - dhcp relay for example (ip-helper adress).

Answer (score 5):

Your assumption is wrong, the mac address of the original host has been stripped away by the first router.

It could be in the payload (i.e. the DATA contains in the packet) but only if the program that generated the data included it which is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The MAC Address in the header of the packet is used for addressing and will always be that of the local L2 link. The originiating MAC Address gets stripped once it leaves it's collision domain and replaced with the gateway to the next collision domain.

Comment: s/collision/broadcast/g

Broadcast domains are separated by gateways/routers not collision domains. There is no need to mac-rewrite within a broadcast domain as by definition it is a L2 realm.

In modern networks for example a 24 port switch that is fully populated will have 24 collision domains but the 24 ports can be part of 1 or more broadcast domains.

Comment: collision domains are seperated by gateways routers AND switches/ports. Each switchport is a seperate collision domain. A hub is an entire collision domain.

Comment: sorry, I guess you ment to correct me, the MAC header is only replaced at broadcast domain level gateway?

Comment: Correct. Mac re-write happens when it crosses a L3 boundary.

For example:

Host A < --- Router --> Host B

Host A will send frame to router(as default gateway) router will know how to get to Host B, change the source mac to it's mac address but keep the src IP address as Host A and dst IP as Host B.

Host B receives this, will send frames back to router with src mac of itself, dst mac of gateway but src IP of itself & dst IP address of Host A. Then mac-rewrite happens in reverse at the router again.